# Why aren't custom views displaying recurring appointments properly?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, list-view, calendar

We have two recurring events in a SharePoint calendar. The first recurs every two weeks beginning Jun 05, 2012, and the second recurs every two weeks beginning Jun 10, 2012. The Jun 05 meeting is intended for Managers only, but the Jun 10 meeting is meant for everyone. I have a metadata field populated with either "Management" or "Staff", and have created two views of the calendar to populate separate Manager and Staff homepages.

Although the meetings are showing up twice per month each on the un-filtered calendars, when I go to my management view ~or~ my staff view, only the main (first) occurences of the meetings show up.

I went back and double checked that I edited the Occurences, not just a single event...and I had. What are some other things I can check to troubleshoot this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an issue with SharePoint in general. You can use the Expanded View which shows recurring events, if you want to customize your view much beyond adding or removing columns you are in need of doing something that really is not OOTB SharePoint. I am very much struggling with this as I am not a "developer" but have found the following in my research that may help you: http://www.sharepointpanda.com/2011/04/sharepoint-2010-calendar-list-views-and-recurring-events-an-adaptation-of-using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/  (this seems like it should work but I really do not know what I am not doing to make it work - think I am combining the scripts wrong??)  Another one with possibility: http://joshmccarty.com/2011/11/sharepoint-jquery-and-fullcalendar%E2%80%94now-with-spservices/  I also found a few more that seemed good but - again, I am inept in programming. So - good luck! Hopefully you find these helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you edit later occurrences in any way they will show up on the lists. I usually go through and add something innocuous to the description. It's annoying, but at least you don't have to do anything OOTB.